# Locate a specific row and column and turn it into an INT

Tags: python

So I've downloaded a CSV, and I'm now trying to locate only a specific row and column that can be turned into a variable.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Import XVA Data
df2 = pd.read_csv('XVA_20180622.csv', sep=',')

#Delete Columns
df2.drop(['Date', 'FVA', 'XVA', 'MtM', 'DVA'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#Getting CVA from today

df3=pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

a= (df2.loc[0, 'CVA'])
a = int(a)

df3['b']=4*(a)

print(df3)

df3.to_csv('20180622.csv', sep =",", index=False)
```

So as you can see, essentially what I've done is download the CSV, deleted all but one column, and now I'm trying to just select a specific row from the one remaining column in the CSV.

This [0, CVA] cell that I am trying to locate is supposed to give me a number, which I can then use as integer, but it's not letting me turn it into an integer.

I've also tried to turn it into a float first, and that did not work either. In the simplest terms, the only thing I'm trying to download from the CSV is this one specific cell, where I can then perform that by things in my other dataframe, which was just downloaded from an SQL file.

The error says:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '73,690,737'
```

Any help would be appreciated, and feel free to ask me to make my question clearer if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '73,690,737'. Added that to post to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `','` from the string

```
temp=str(df2.loc[0,'CVA'])
temp=temp.replace(",",'')
int(temp)
```

If all the column values are int you can convert the entire series but as you mentioned in your post you are just dealing with single cell then you may proceed with above example. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: What **','** am I removing? The one inside df2=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=',')? Or is it somewhere else that I do that?

Comment: Just try replacing the part of the code where you are trying to convert the value into `int`.